# WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/helpme/hi] in DispatcherServlet with name 'hello'

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm trying to do a simple HelloWorld using Spring MVC, but even though I followed some tutorial (on udemy and tutorialspoint) step-by-step and importing the exactly same dependecies it keeps raising this exception when i call `localhost:8080/[project-name]/hi` :

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/helpme/hi] in DispatcherServlet with name 'hello'
```

But typing only

```
localhost:8080/[project-name]
```

shows a index.jsp correctly.

I'm using Tomcat v8.5 and JRE 1.8 .
I use Eclipse as IDE (don't think this is relevant...)

Here is my code:

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.od.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>helpme</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>helpme Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

**hello-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.me.controller" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" name="resolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
"-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
"http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.me.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

        @RequestMapping("/hi")
        public ModelAndView hello() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("hello");
        return mav;
    }

}
```

My project structure is correct:
Under src>main>resources there is my package com.me.controller
Under the 'webapp' folder i have WEB-INF>views>hello.jsp

I looked all over the web, even here on stackoverflow (I know there are a LOT of issues like mine), and I tried any code variation i could find, but no answer seems to solve it.

Comment: show the package for the controller class.

Comment: Ok i added it to the code, it's "com.me.controller"

Answer (score 0):

I replicated the same thing in my eclipse and successful. Fixed an issue in your Hello Controller, you did not import ModelAndView and there is no method called setName for ModelAndView, find updated below. Just FYI, I am using Tomcat 8.0.36 and Java 8, that should not make a difference though.

```
package com.me.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hi")
    public ModelAndView hello() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("hello");
    return mav;
}

}
```

[image: This is my project structure, make sure you have in similar way]

Comment: It now raises a parsing exception with the following message: the corresponding jolly character is strict but it's not possible to find a declaration for element <mvc:annotation-driven/>

Comment: @odysseas  check my updated answer, this is cause ur missing MVC in the declaration.

Comment: @Jhon the latter exception is gone, so it works, but it didn't solve the main issue...

Comment: @odysseas check my updated answer. Give it a thumbs up if it works. :) Cheers

Comment: look, I'm really sorry but I noticed that mistake after posting but I forgot to update the code here (so thanks for notifying me)... Anyway the code still doesn't work. Also, i downloaded the example code from the course (I copied avery single character from the video) and it works well... I can't figure out where is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I have had to define a servlet in web.xml but I beleieve your url pattern needs to be /*

Comment: It doesn't work; I already tried that before asking here and I tried again right now. With /* it can't even find index.jsp...

Answer (score 0):

I solved. It was an Eclipse problem.

In my project structure I noticed a folder named "Deployed Resources" in which I found the webapp directory with all the files. The problem was that the file web.xml contained in that directory was the default one with all the welcome files listed and nothing more, so Tomcat couldn't (obviously) find map the request. I changed it with my file and it worked. I don't know why this happened, I think I'll check very well Eclipse settings.

Thanks a lot to everyone for the help.